# InvalidArgumentException: The specified translation (fr) cannot be removed

Tags: drush

Configurations:

```
"drupal/core": "8.4.3",
"acquia/blt": "8.9.10",
"acquia/lightning": "2.2.5",
```

I am trying to run migration of workbench moderation to content moderation on drupal core version 8.4.3, Install that module `wbm2cm` and run below the commands,

```
$ drush wbm2cm-save
$ drush wbm2cm-clear
$ drush pm-uninstall workbench_moderation
$ drush en content_moderation
$ drush wbm2cm-restore
```

After run `drush wbm2cm-restore` getting the error:

> InvalidArgumentException: The specified translation (fr) cannot be
>   removed. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->removeTranslation()
>   (line 901 of
>   /var/www/cgicom/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).
>   The specified translation (fr) cannot be removed.
>   (/var/www/cgicom/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php:805)

My References: 
https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/fixing-invalid-translations-drupal-8-content-moderation
https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_clone/issues/2984049

Here I am not getting the solutions. Please can anyone suggest me?

Comment: Module in beta since 2018... You should try dev and/or raise an issue on https://www.drupal.org/project/wbm2cm.

Comment: Ok. I will raise on issue queue on wbm2cm. 
Thanks @leymannx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the mentioned module is third-party and this is probably a bug that need to be filed on https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/wbm2cm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"#3" patch file is working to me!
https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-03-26/3043535-no-failure-deleting-multiple-translations-3.patch

Please refer: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3043535